# How to download, decompress and transfer multiple files directly into an s3 bucket?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, etl

My problem is the following: I would like to download a  dataset hosted somewhere using its url, decompress it and upload the files (e.g. images) to an s3 bucket. An example of dataset could be CIFAR-100: https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar.html and the dataset url would be https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar-100-python.tar.gz

Note that in some cases the dataset is huge, so downloading it first to my local computer is simply not an option. I thought about creating a pipe to do it as streamlined as possible. The command below works for single files (e.g. single image):

```
curl "url/single_image.tar.gz" | tar xvz | aws s3 cp - s3://my_bucket/single_image.jpg
```

But if the compressed folder contains e.g. multiple images, the command above does not longer work since it requires to specify the destination filename and extension.

Which is the simplest solution to this problem?

Comment: You may create an EC2 instance in the same region as your bucket and execute the command there.. Maybe even create an S3 VPC endpoint for the time. as well you may want to separate the commands (using && instead of pipe)

Comment: May actually be a faster option to try out, the pipe approach is painfully slow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use gnu tar with the [`--to-command`](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Writing-to-an-External-Program.html) option which allows you to:

> Extract files and pipe their contents to the standard input of command. When this option is used, instead of creating the files specified, tar invokes command and pipes the contents of the files to its standard output.

It even supports the following:

> The command can obtain the information about the file it processes from the following environment variables:
>
> TAR_FILENAME The name of the file.

The following command should do what you want:

```
curl https://xxxxx/test.tar | tar -xz --to-command='aws s3 cp - s3://bucket/$TAR_FILENAME'
```

Comment: Sorry at this moment don't have access to S3 to try this out in full but it should work.

Comment: Thanks, @AshamanKingpin! Which should be the command,then? I will try it out. I looked into it here but is not clear to me yet: https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Writing-to-an-External-Program.html I also realized just now that my command was not working the way it expected. It does copy a csv into s3 bucket but not the one extracted so there was an issue already there.

Comment: Sorry, that was the doc link I was looking at too, I should have added that to my answer.  I have an AWS setup at home and I will try it this evening if you don't solve it by then or no one else chimes in.  Interesting question though!

Comment: It seems to me it can be solved with curl "url/images.tar.gz" | tar xvz \
> --to-command="sh -c $(printf '%q' 'aws s3 cp - "s3://my_bucket/$TAR_FILENAME"')" but it is painfully slow

Comment: Interesting, how does your command behave differently from mine?  Not sure the slowness can be avoided, you have to download the huge data set, uncompress it, and upload each file individually.  All that is going to take time.  Hmm, I interpreted this statement of yours "downloading it first to my local computer is simply not an option" as your way of expressing concern with the amount of  storage it would consume locally and not that you are going to actually find a way to avoid downloading it first.  Downloading it first somewhere is unavoidable.

Comment: Yes, your command has the same effect as mine. I just needed do change the order a bit: curl -k "url" | tar -xzv --to-command='aws s3 cp - s3://bucket/$TAR_FILENAME' Do you mind editing your answer and I will accept it?

Comment: I can move the -x after the tar command for aesthetics but the other options you specify don't really add to the "correctness" of the answer and are options which are specific to your environment.  Do you mind if I keep the answer as is (except for moving the -x option) as I believe it is more generally applicable?  Future readers can augment the basic command with additional options to fit their environment.

Comment: sorry, I meant the -z was missing (.tar -> archive is compressed), the order indeed does not matter